# Why WebApi when we have WCF RESTful services as well as ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF Service or Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502548/wcf-service-or-web-api)

What sort of applications does WebApi target as we already have different .net frameworks like MVC, wcf services already doing what Webapi promises?

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't been following along for the past couple years, you might get some value out of reading [one of Glenn Block's original posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gblock/archive/2010/11/01/wcf-web-apis-http-your-way.aspx) on the topic.

Despite the fact that this post is quite old at this point and many, many changes have occurred in the framework since (most notably the merge with ASP.NET MVC), this post gives some insight into why the project was started in the first place.