# Create one ServiceHost with two Endpoints (two different interface implementations)

Tags: .net, wcf, service

I am new to WCF and I am trying to understand how Services work now.

My question is simple:

I have an Interface: **ICalculator**

I have 2 implementations: **StandardCalculator** : ICalculator  and **FunkyCalculator** : ICalculator

And I would like to know how I can expose this (code wise) so that the URL's are like this:

hxxp://localhost:8000/**Calculator/Simple**

hxxp://localhost:8000/**Calculator/Funky**

If this is not possible to do I would like to understand why.

Comment: This looks more like a RESTful Web API to me. Perhaps ASP.NET Web API is a better fit?

Comment: oh I see. So WCF was not created for this kind of thing then. Is it even possible to do it?

Comment: It is [certainly possible](https://www.google.com/search?q=WCF+Rest) to do REST with WCF. [Here is a discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502548/wcf-service-or-web-api) about picking WCF REST or Web API.

Comment: You have two different implementations of one contract, so you have two different services.  Ergo, you'll need two separate service hosts.  You could use multiple endpoints for a **single** service (a single implementation of a single contract).

Comment: @Steven - I disagree that this looks RESTful; this looks like a standard WCF SOAP to me.