# Designing an API-centric application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My boss has acquired a company that does ERP solutions, and wants me to rewrite their package so that it is a web-based solution.  I have previous experience writing web applications but this time, because down the line on the roadmap, he wants to create an iOS and Android app to compliment this system.

I figured the best way to prepare for this is to shift the entire business logic into an API, so that we wont have to rewrite the logic.

My question is how would I go about separating the business logic from the MVC architecture into the WebAPI framework?

Comment: Sounds like this might be a good fit for building a WCF web-service layer.

Comment: I have no experience with the WCF web-service layer. What makes it different from the webAPI framework?

Comment: I actually think you are on the right track by using the Web API framework.  I was not aware of it until just now, but apparently it supersedes WCF for build RESTful services - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348639/wcf-vs-asp-net-web-api

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for that article. it was an interesting read.