# WCF 4.5 REST-style services, what is missing? Why WCF REST is not a true REST? Why ASP.NET Web API is better approach than WCF 4.5?

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api, soa, restful-architecture

Below MSDN article says that

"WCF provides some support for writing REST-style services, the support for REST in ASP.NET Web API is more complete and all future REST feature improvements will be made in ASP.NET Web API."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx

Can somebody please tell me what all is missing in WCF REST-style services because of that it is not complete and one should consider ASP.NET Web API for Restful implementation of services?

Comment: If you can use ASP.NET Web Api that would be the best approach. WCF is not a true REST

Comment: Hummm..., every body saying this and this exactly what I am looking for. Why WCF REST is not a true REST?

Comment: Dalorzo, I am looking for: Why ASP.NET Web API is better approach against WCF REST?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348639/wcf-vs-asp-net-web-api/16345040#16345040

Comment: @Manish: thats the comparison between WCF vs WEB API. I am comparing WCF-REST vs WEB API.

Comment: @Vipul **WCF is WCF**.  It is incorrect to think of a an offshoot as _"WCF-REST"_.  By decorating your methods and configuring accordingly, you can change your say TCP SOAP service to exhibit REST tendancies.  However as others have said, REST support in WCF is not as complete as in ASP.NET Web API