# Difference between WCF REST VS WEB API

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap, asp.net-web-api

I think WCF uses SOAP protocol. WebAPI uses rest architecture. But WCF supports both SOAP and REST.

1. What is difference between WCF REST and WebAPI?
2. Why is there a general preference for WebAPI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF vs ASP.NET Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348639/wcf-vs-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: this link will clear all your doubts.
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/JI2X050413-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-API-and-WCF-REST-and-Web-Service.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF is protocol agnostic. It can run over http, tcpip, net pipes, etc.
Web API is more suited for building rest apis.

However, your question is too broad to be answered here. Read more about both technologies and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: It has to be said that even though WCF with webHttpBinding allows you to build fully functional REST API, it seems easier to do it with Web API as WCF was not designed for REST services at first.