# WebAPI or WCF with svc file

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a RestFull service.
In c# .Net in Visual studio 2012  framework 4.5

Do I need to create a web api for this?

Or can I create a project with .svc file and manage this?(I dont remeber what sort of project is this)

Which is the best way

Comment: The following Stack Overflow post seems to address your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348639/wcf-vs-asp-net-web-api

Comment: have a look at nancy - http://nancyfx.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, There is no answer that one is better than the other.  Fortunately, there is a fairly straightforward way of determining which framework to use when building a new web service. My general rule of thumb is: If it's an internal/intranet web service, use WCF; if it's an external/internet web service, use Web API.

To prevent creating a whole Web API for this the best way would be creating a project with .svc file and manage it. Easier , faster and "safer"!

Comment: And a WCF service project can produce both SOAP and REST endpoints in the same project, mostly with the same code.

Answer (score -1):

Without doubt wCF for internal and rest for external facing

Comment: What if the external-facing wants to use SOAP? Perhaps because of rich metadata, or, features?