# Angular2 and .net service

Tags: wcf, angular, asp.net-web-api

Would like to know which will be a better option to use with Angular2 along with .net framework. Will it be WCF or Web API. The .Net service will actually be used to load data models. All the other activities like routing etc will be done in Angular2.

Are there any advantages of using Web API or is it actually required in this case since the .Net service is used only purely for data access. To get Load product, category and customer data, to get the searched list, to save and edit product and customer data, also for creating orders etc

Comment: I'm afraid this is opinion-based. In both frameworks you can create a service that outputs JSON, which is what you'll want. For "Which to choose, WebAPI or WCF" there are plenty of resources out there helping you decide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF vs ASP.NET Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348639/wcf-vs-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: I'd say it depends on what you know, and what kind of database you want. Where I work we have most our projects in C#, and typically use something like Entity Framework with SQL for our databases - so .NET ASP is natural for the backend. However, if you're using MongoDB, probably no need for the .NET.

I've found .NET and Angular 2 quite easy to work with together so far, once I found the right template to get me started.

Comment: Neither. Use NancyFx http://nancyfx.org/