# Web Services, WCF, etc.

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am using asp.net for development that uses both web forms and mvc.

I have some code in in an application that produces a downloadable excel file. If there are any validation issues, it shows issues in why the program cannot produce the excel file.

My question is what is the best way to create this code so that it is shared between multiple C# applications that use either MVC or Web Forms. I am new to web services to thinking of using that but I understand there is WCF and also MS Web APIs. Just looking for some suggestions. As mentioned, the code will either produce a downloadable excel file or show validation errors on why it could not produce it due to data issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually there is no such thing as best way. you can use asmx, wcf or web api. its completely up to you.
if you use asmx you can only write a soap web services.
if you use web API you only have restful.
but with wcf you have both soap and restful.
here you can read more about .net web services technology:
[WCF vs ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348639/wcf-vs-asp-net-web-api)