# Web API vs Window Communication Foundation

Tags: api, wcf

I read bunch of articles about SOAP and REST(WCF and Web API). 
And after all the reading I end up with understanding that WCF is more powerful, but lots of it's functionality can be implemented in Web API. For example for duplex communication in web API we can use SignalR or sockets. WCF gives you more security with WS-Security, but in Web API you can use HTTPs
So what can WCF give you that Web API cant, except working with lots of different protocols and data formats?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF vs ASP.NET Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348639/wcf-vs-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WCF` supports more protocols and transports than `Web Api`, some of then very useful, like `SOAP`, `FTP` and `MSMQ`.

Here you have a table comparing both: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172.aspx

[image]

Both has their own purposes, and the table above can help you to choose.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are using for different scenario WebApi uses full features of Restful services like Uri caching and various other features .Check the below difference I hope it will help you

[image]